How to Retrieve Google OAuth Access Token with NextAuth.js and Prisma in Next.js 14?
I'm building an application using Next.js 14, NextAuth.js, and Prisma ORM. I successfully set up Google OAuth to enable user login with Google, and everything works well. However, I need to retrieve the access token generated by Google to use it in my API requests (e.g., creating Google Meet links on behalf of the user).
Here's my setup:
Prisma schema: I have a model for Account where I've set fields for access_token, refresh_token, etc.
NextAuth configuration: I’m using GoogleProvider with appropriate scopes in the authorization params.
Auth callback: I've tried configuring the session callback in NextAuth to include the accessToken, but it doesn't seem to persist in the session object.
The endpoint where I need the accessToken checks if it exists in the session, but right now, it’s returning undefined.
How can I ensure the access token is available in the session for use in my API requests?
Here's my current code setup:
// src/app/api/meet/creating-meet/route.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import axios from 'axios';
import { auth } from "@/services/auth";
import { z } from 'zod';

const createMeetSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(1).max(100)
});

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const session = await auth();

  if (!session || !session.user?.accessToken) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Unauthorized' }, { status: 401 });
  }

  try {
    const body = await req.json();
    const parsedBody = createMeetSchema.parse(body);
    const response = await axios.post(
      'https://meet.googleapis.com/v2/spaces',
      {
        name: parsedBody.name,
        config: {
          accessType: 'OPEN',
          entryPointAccess: 'ALL'
        }
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${session.user.accessToken}`
        }
      }
    );

    return NextResponse.json(response.data, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Error creating meeting' }, { status: 500 });
  }
}


 // src/lib/auth/index.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import EmailProvider from 'next-auth/providers/nodemailer'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

import { PrismaAdapter } from '@auth/prisma-adapter'
import { prisma } from '../database'
import { createStripeCustomer } from '../stripe'

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth
} = NextAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth',
    signOut: '/auth',
    error: '/auth',
    verifyRequest: '/auth',
    newUser: '/app'
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    EmailProvider({
      server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER,
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: 'openid profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meetings.space.created'
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  events: {
    createUser: async message => {
      await createStripeCustomer({
        name: message.user.name as string,
        email: message.user.email as string
      })
    }
  }
})


I configured the NextAuth session callback to include the accessToken by adding it from the token object. I expected the accessToken to be available in session.user.accessToken after login, so I could use it in my API routes. However, despite setting up the callback and including the token in the session object, session.user.accessToken still returns undefined when accessed in my API endpoint.
